# Facebook.ui method: 'apprequests' hangs only on local development environment but not on anything else

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I used this guide to set up the apprequest dialog. More specifically, I am using `sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector` to allow a user to select multiple friends to send the app request to. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

I set this up almost a month ago and it's been working fine on my local development environment. However, today, for whatever reason, it just hangs. I can see requests going to Facebook and all the thumbnails being returned for my friends, but it doesn't seem to get past the 'loading' image.

The other weird thing is that on all my deployment environments (i.e., staging, production), it works just fine.

I checked the Facebook App I use for local development, and I'm not too sure how this happened, but the app id and app secret had changed. I've updated them accordingly but still to no avail.

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. The following solved the problem:

1. Define a custom domain in the hosts file (on the local computer),
   as described earlier in this thread.
2. Configure Visual Studio to use port 80. Don't use a custom
   (or random port).
3. Update the facebook App settings with the custom domain.

If you use a custom port, like 4543, the facebook dialogs will hang.

http://www.lazerwire.com

Comment: Same issue as poster. Moving to port 80 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your local development server and the production (or any other server you want to run the script from) runs on the same domain (or subdomain of it) as the app domain that you've set in the application setting (in facebook developers site, http://developers.facebook.com/apps )

Comment: Thanks for your response. The only environment that is affected is my local environment - all other environments are fine. I'm not sure if I'm following you entirely. Do you mean I should add `localhost` in the App Domains input?

Comment: you cannot add localhost to the app domain... you need to define a subdomain on your systems host file that will refer to 127.0.0.1 (localhost), and access your local site through that domain. (in windows the file is in C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts )

Answer (score 0):

Another possible workaround is to set display:'popup' in the FB.ui call. The described bug does not occur for this display method.